# Google Cloud - TCP health check for named/bind dns serevr

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a DNS server on Google Cloud. I'd like to use a TCP load balancer before it. I setup a health check, but it doesn't work.

My config:

```
myhealthcheck
Protocol
TCP
Port
53
Proxy protocol
NONE
Interval
5 seconds
Timeout
5 seconds
Unhealthy threshold
2 consecutive failures
Healthy threshold
2 consecutive successes
```

Can I use a TCP health check with a bind/named server? (port 53)

Comment: Can you elaborate more by explaining what error are you getting?

Comment: as I see, Google Cloud doesn't support every TCP port, like 53:

_TCP Proxy Load Balancing supports the following ports: 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, 5222_

source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy

Comment: To get clearer idea about your scenario, can you let me know whether you have configured **bind server** (or servers?) for DNS on top of GCE VM(s)? Also, are you trying to manage the bind servers with TCP LB?

Comment: Yes, I installed a bing server on GCE VM, and I'd like to use TCP LB in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

DNS queries are done over UDP and therefore the creation of a TCP health check won't be able to do what you're trying here. Try setting the protocol to UDP.

Comment: There is already a more correct answer in the comments.

Comment: I beg to disagree. No comment is talking about DNS traffic not being TCP traffic and therefore not able to be health checked with a TCP health check. It gives an answer, but in such an incomplete way that the original poster could easily make a similar kind of mistake in the future.

Comment: DNS traffic certainly can be TCP.